# how to set up SEO title and meta description in weebly online store products category pages

Tags: seo, weebly

I have a simple query in weebly web-site i have updated SEO title and meta description on product category pages but it is not update on website.

is there any another options to update SEO title and Meta description on weebly website.?

here i am update the SEO title and description in weebly web-site[here i update SEO title and meta description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mcWD.png)
[it is not shown on that product category page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkWLm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably by the phrase SEO titles you mean meta titles. 
Check **[the metadata value from Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata)**:

> Metadata is "data information that provides information about other
>   data".

Probably meta titles and meta descriptions can be attributed to descriptive metadata. Therefore, let's check the value for this category of metadata:

> Descriptive metadata is descriptive information about a resource. It
>   is used for discovery and identification.

Thus, the meta-elements you have specified can be used as online identifiers for each web page on your website.

The attached screenshot is seen in the meta elements you use an abbreviation such as *CBD*. Much mention of the abbreviations in your meta elements can be seen as **[keyword stuffing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66358)**.
Also in the meta description, you use some kind of URL. This may prevent you from scanning text for voice search (text to speech). Use the correct grammar in the meta elements and do not use characters such as $ as you have it.

In addition, the content of these meta elements is difficult to consider as descriptive and it is difficult to consider it as an identifier for the content of a web page. Phrases such as Best and Popular, if this does not have explicit confirmation, can be attributed to advertising, but not to the description or to the ID.

Check out the following **[Google guidelines for meta titles and meta descriptions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624)**:

> - Page titles should be descriptive and concise.
> - Avoid keyword stuffing. It's sometimes helpful to have a few descriptive terms in the title, but there’s no reason to have the
>     same words or phrases appear multiple times.
> - Avoid repeated or boilerplate titles.
> - Brand your titles, but concisely. Include clearly tagged facts in the description.

The fact that Google ignores the content of your meta elements may be a signal that this content is not relevant to the content of the web page. 
This is confirmed by the following information from the specified guidelines:

> If you’re seeing your pages appear in the search results with modified
>   titles, check whether your titles have one of the problems described
>   above. If not, consider whether the alternate title is a better fit
>   for the query.